# > fails when value negative

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
// evaluates to negative numbers, i.e. -2 
$group_vids_count = $_videos->countGroupVids($series['id']) - 3; 
if ( $group_vids_count > 0 )
{
   $xmore = $group_vids_count . ' is more';
}
else
{
   $xmore = $group_vids_count;
}
```

Everything works as expected if `$group_vids_count` evaluates to a positive number. As far as it evaluates to a negative number, like -2 I still get results as if `$group_vids_count > 0`, although -2 is < 0...

`$_videos->countGroupVids($series['id']) - 3` is intended as there are 3 videos displayed directly. I need to find out how many more there are...

I have tried to use `max()` but still the same issue...

Comment: Not that it helps anything with the weird error you are encountering, why don't you simply test for `$vids_count > 3`?

Comment: You are certain that `$_videos->countGroupVids($series['id']) - 3 == -2`?

Comment: @Michael - Yes, since I have a series with 1 video, so -3 = -2

Comment: @knittl - can't do that since I also need to find out the number of vids beyond 3

Comment: @MichalPlško But you have actually verified by echoing out the value, that the method `countGroupVids()` works properly and returns the value it is supposed to?

Comment: Maybe you have an issue with the countGroupVids returning a string instead of an integer? Try typecasting it!

Comment: try `var_dump($group_vids_count)`

Comment: try like this

    $group_vids_count = intval($_videos->countGroupVids($series['id']) - 3);

Comment: @Michael - Yes, it's verifyed... Strange enough, I know... Can't understand that too... I have evena new issue with this - see the edit :)

Comment: In my experience, such problems are best answered using [xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) and breakpoints.

Comment: @DCoder - I don't use it and really, this MUST be a simple issue, don't want to bother for now with that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce that problem, see [this codepad example](http://codepad.org/TO3ROhXY). Are you sure `$group_vids_count` is actually negative?

Answer (score 0):

some problem with your logic try this code it works fine

```
<?php
$group_vids_count = -2; 
if ( $group_vids_count > 0 )
{
   $xmore = "possitive";
}
else
{
   $xmore = "negative";
}
echo $xmore;
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

For some reason `$group_vids_count = max(0,$group_vids_count);` did the trick now... Thanx everybody anyways...